# Newtonsoft.JSON serializeobject returns empty JSON string

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

Everyone got this question a lot, and I tried almost everything but none of it works for me.

So I am developing in Xamarin.Forms and is about to send my data to the server. I have this class:

```
public class Customer
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Then I used Newtonsoft's SerializeObject method:

```
Customer customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = FirstName.Text,
            LastName = LastName.Text,
            BirthDate = BirthDate.Date.ToString(),
            EmailAddress = Email.Text,
            Password = Password.Text,
            ContactNumber = Mobile.Text
        };


        var item = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
```

But variable `item` results in a string containing an empty JSON object `{}`. Is something wrong with my implementation?

EDIT: Also, I noticed that although my Customer class and its members are public, the debugger still counts them as "non-public" members. Please see "screenshot of debugger":

[image: Screenshot of debugger]

Comment: get rid of the [Serializable] attribute

Comment: I doubt SerializeObject returns null if passing in "an object". It should still return "some JSON" (or *a string*), even if it doesn't serialize as expected.

Comment: *Also, I noticed that although my Customer class is public, its members are non-public* -- if that is true, then they will not be serialized.  See [Why are some members missing when trying to print an object by serializing to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48156976/3744182) for an explanation and options to fix.  However, in your question, the properties *are* public.  So, which is it?

Comment: @dbc Please see the "screenshot of debugger" although i've set every member to public, the debugger counts them as non-public.

Comment: @Lala - well that's a bit mysterious.  What if you try some of the workarounds from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48156976/3744182) such as marking your public properties with `[JsonProperty]`?

Comment: `FirstName.Text`, `LastName.Text`, etc. are not null?

Comment: @BrunoPeres they are not.

Comment: @dbc did that, to no avail

Comment: @Jason got rid off, still no luck

Comment: Then maybe related or duplicate: [JsonConvert.SerializeObject always return {} in XamarinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48041823/3744182).

Comment: @dbc that's it!! I plugged my device via USB (instead of Xamarin Live Player) and now it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Xamarin Live Player has some issues with the serializer. I tried plugging my phone via USB and it works!

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little misleading since you show your class properties as public.

> Also, I noticed that although my Customer class is public, its members are non-public:

WIth that being said these are your options:

1. If your properties can be public, make them public
2. If the properties need to remain private, add the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to them

Comment: Apologies for that, what I meant was - I've set them all to public. But the debugger still counts them as "non-public". Please see "screenshot of debugger"

Comment: @Lala your backing fields are non publics, but your properties are public.