# JsonConvert.Serialize returning {}

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently working on a Xamarin project, however facing an issue where object being serialized returns `{}`. May I have some advice on this?

Here's my entity class

```
public class TodoItem
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public bool Done { get; set; }

    }
```

The code where I serialize my object

```
public async Task SaveTodoItemAsync(TodoItem item, bool isNewItem = false)
        {
            //RestUrl = refer to constants.cs
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));

            try
            {

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, 
                "application/json");

               ...
            }
        }
```

Also, I have noticed when I try to insert data, they all lies in `non-public members`. Could that been the cause?

[image: Sample]

Comment: You don't need to attribute your properties, they are automatically added. It is only needed if you want to call them something else when output or if you want to ignore the property.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I only added them when the serializing wasn't working. So even without the attributes, it doesn't work

Comment: are you sure your item is not null?

Comment: @Jason I traced, the content variable is null, but the json variable is {}

Comment: no, I mean does the item that you are serializing have values in its properties?

Comment: @Jason Yes, they have values in them. But they're under non-public members.

Comment: What do you mean?  The TodoItem class you posted ONLY has 4 public properties, nothing else.

Comment: @Jason I have a UI page which will insert the values into them.

Comment: Are you using the Xamarin Live Player app?  If so this is a duplicate of [JsonConvert.SerializeObject always return {} in XamarinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48041823/3744182) and [Newtonsoft.JSON serializeobject returns empty JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48914561/3744182).  See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=android which indicates there is *Limited support for reflection (currently affects some popular NuGets, like SQLite and Json.NET).*.

Comment: @dbc Didn't manage to find these articles, read them and it's exactly the problem I am facing. Thank you