# json.deserialize returns null + xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net, deserialization

i am getting response text like this from web api call

```
{
    "response":{"numFound":4661,"start":0,"maxScore":6.3040514,"docs":[..]  }
}
```

i am trying to deserialize  it like this

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBodyAsText);
```

this is my c# class:

```
public class Doc
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string journal { get; set; }
public string eissn { get; set; }
public DateTime publication_date { get; set; }
public string article_type { get; set; }
public List<string> author_display { get; set; }
public List<string> @abstract { get; set; }
public string title_display { get; set; }
public double score { get; set; }
}


 public class Response
{
public int numFound { get; set; }
public int start { get; set; }
public double maxScore { get; set; }
public List<Doc> docs { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{
public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Full SOURCE CODE:

```
namespace CrossSampleApp1.Common
{
public class ServiceManager<T>
{
    public delegate void SucessEventHandler(T responseData, bool 
      HasMoreRecords = false);
    public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(ErrorData responseData);

    public event SucessEventHandler OnSuccess;
    public event ErrorEventHandler OnError;

    public async Task JsonWebRequest(string url, string contents, HttpMethod methodType, string mediaStream = "application/json")
    {
        bool isSuccessRequest = true;
        string responseBodyAsText = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(methodType, url);
                if (methodType == HttpMethod.Post)
                {
                    message.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
                    message.Content = new StringContent(contents);
                    message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contents.Length;
                    message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaStream);
                }

                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            //responseBodyAsText = "Exception : " + hre.Message;
            responseBodyAsText = "Can't Connect (Please check your network connection)";
            isSuccessRequest = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  responseBodyAsText = "Exception : " + ex.Message;
            responseBodyAsText = "Can't Connect (Please check your network connection)";
            isSuccessRequest = false;
        }

        try
        {
            if (isSuccessRequest)
            {
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                {
                    OnSuccess?.Invoke((T)(object)responseBodyAsText);
                }
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ServiceResponse))
                {
                    T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseBodyAsText);
                    OnSuccess?.Invoke(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBodyAsText);
                    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Convert.ToString(result));
                    OnSuccess?.Invoke(data);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                OnError?.Invoke(new ErrorData
                {
                    ErrorText = responseBodyAsText
                });

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            OnError?.Invoke(new ErrorData
            {
                ErrorText = e.Message
            });
        }
    }

}

public class ErrorData : EventArgs
{
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

}

but i am getting null value in result.can anyone help.what i am doing wrong

thank you.

Comment: Are you actually deserializing to the type `RootObject` somewhere? Or are you trying to cast it using `as`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as the given code gives me a non-null `result` value, contrary to what you're saying it does.

Comment: Just FYI, you're not actually using the classes you've mentioned though, since you're using the non-generic version of `.DeserializeObject`, which means you'll get back a `JObject`. If you later have `result as RootObject`, then yes, you will get a `null`. This, however, is why we need a [mcve], to see *exactly* what you're doing.

Comment: oh.god i dont whts wrong with this site.i have posted var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBodyAsText);

stil it is not reflecting same

Comment: unable to edit even.

Comment: @Neelam best not to put your code in as a quote.

Comment: @john oh..y that was creating issue.thank for notify me..pls check edit

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]? Your code [works fine](http://rextester.com/UPHK60737).

Comment: i tried to make it minimal nd simplied as much it can be..

Comment: @Neelam It's the "verifiable" part that's missing. Your example doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: please check edit. i have updated full source code.. i m missing something or doing anything wrong?

Comment: `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Convert.ToString(result));` Uhh, unless the `ToString()` method of `RootObject` is overloaded to return a JSON object, then `Convert.ToString()` doesn't do what you think it does. `Convert.ToString(instanceOfRootObject)` will return "CrossSampleApp1.Common.RootObject" (if RootObject is in the "CrossSampleApp1.Common" namespace)

Comment: but i dont get value even its above line of code.in deserilization.so issue must be there i think

Comment: Then your input string is wrong.

Comment: you mean to say responseBodyAsText? but is is same i got from web api call

Comment: Well, something's wrong  Sorry

Comment: Are you using the Xamarin Forms live player?  If so, it apparently doesn't work with Json.NET due to lack of support for reflection.  See [JsonConvert.SerializeObject always return {} in XamarinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48041823/3744182) and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/limitations/

Comment: And see also https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119749/newtonsoft-json-serializeobject-and-deserializeobject-returning-null

Answer (score 1):

This will not work:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBodyAsText);
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Convert.ToString(result));
OnSuccess?.Invoke(data);
```

You deserialize a `string` `responseBodyAsString` to an object of type `RootObject`. Afterwards you convert the object to string and try to deserialize this string (whatever it may contain) to T.

I'm guessing that `result.response` should be your data.

I'm not sure what you problem is. Perhaps that you forgot to name the type which you want to deserialize.

Here some example deserialization:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Example-data
    string jsonInput = "{ \"response\":{\"numFound\":4661,\"start\":0,\"maxScore\":6.3040514,\"docs\":[\"a\",\"b\"] } }";
    // deserialize the inputData to out class "RootObject"
    RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonInput);

    // Let's see if we got something in our object:
    Console.WriteLine("NumFound: " + r.response.numFound);
    Console.WriteLine("Start: " + r.response.start);
    Console.WriteLine("MaxScrote: " + r.response.maxScore);
    Console.WriteLine("Docs: " + string.Join(", ", r.response.docs));

    Console.WriteLine("-- let's have a look to our Deserializer without giving a type --");

    object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{ \"response\":{\"numFound\":4661,\"start\":0,\"maxScore\":6.3040514,\"docs\":[\"a\",\"b\"] } }");
    Console.WriteLine("Type: " + o.GetType());
    JObject j = o as JObject;
    Console.WriteLine(j["response"]);
    Console.WriteLine("NumFound: " + j["response"]["numFound"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Start: " + j["response"]["start"]);
    Console.WriteLine("MaxScrote: " + j["response"]["maxScore"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Docs: " + String.Join(", ", j["response"]["docs"].Select(s => s.ToString())));
}

public class Response
{
    public int numFound { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public double maxScore { get; set; }
    public List<string> docs { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your raply but i have tried same
 RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonInput);

Comment: but in post i dont knw why its not reflecting like that

Comment: The deserialization has nothing to do with your http-action. Perhaps your input data is not correct? Extended the example which is working.

Comment: sorry didnt get it wht u r trying to say

Comment: Post your sourcecode and we will find your problem. The snippets you posted are correct. My example uses your snippets and works.

Comment: i am getting respocebody text from web api call.but at time of deserializtion i get null in my result

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati I don't understand what your code should do. You should test it step by step. Added comment to your deserialize to the answer.

Comment: type is : Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why you want to serialize to JObject?!

Comment: i am tying to make sample app for web api call intergration in xamarin.app.

the code below menitoned that i took from one reference project.

Comment: so i am trying to integrate that with my web api.

Comment: `Response responseResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBodyAsText).response;`